# Calculate difference between 'times' rows in DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, row, difference

My DataFrame is in the Form:

```
       TimeWeek   TimeSat  TimeHoli
0      6:40:00   8:00:00   8:00:00
1      6:45:00   8:05:00   8:05:00
2      6:50:00   8:09:00   8:10:00
3      6:55:00   8:11:00   8:14:00
4      6:58:00   8:13:00   8:17:00
5      7:40:00   8:15:00   8:21:00
```

I need to find the time difference between each row in TimeWeek , TimeSat and TimeHoli, the output must be

```
TimeWeekDiff   TimeSatDiff  TimeHoliDiff
00:05:00          00:05:00       00:05:00
00:05:00          00:04:00       00:05:00
00:05:00          00:02:00       00:04:00  
00:03:00          00:02:00       00:03:00
00:02:00          00:02:00       00:04:00
```

I tried using `(d['TimeWeek']-df['TimeWeek'].shift().fillna(0)` , it throws an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Probably because of the presence of ':' in the column. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the error is thrown because the data is in the form of a string instead of a timestamp.  First convert them to timestamps:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: [pd.Timestamp(ts) for ts in x])
```

They will contain today's date by default, but this shouldn't matter once you difference the time (hopefully you don't have to worry about differencing 23:55 and 00:05 across dates).

Once converted, simply difference the DataFrame:

```
>>> df2 - df2.shift()
   TimeWeek  TimeSat  TimeHoli
0       NaT      NaT       NaT
1  00:05:00 00:05:00  00:05:00
2  00:05:00 00:04:00  00:05:00
3  00:05:00 00:02:00  00:04:00
4  00:03:00 00:02:00  00:03:00
5  00:42:00 00:02:00  00:04:00
```

Depending on your needs, you can just take rows 1+ (ignoring the NaTs):

```
(df2 - df2.shift()).iloc[1:, :]
```

or you can fill the NaTs with zeros:

```
(df2 - df2.shift()).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Forget everything I just said. Pandas has great timedelta parsing.

```
df["TimeWeek"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["TimeWeek"])
(d['TimeWeek']-df['TimeWeek'].shift().fillna(pd.to_timedelta("00:00:00"))
```

Comment: I tried this, got an error:                                                                                   raise ValueError("cannot create timedelta string converter for [{0}]".format(r))
ValueError: cannot create timedelta string converter for [6:40:00]

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Pandas can only parse `06:40:00`, not `6:40:00`. A little string manipulation should get you there. Prefix any value that's too short with a 0, and then try again.

Comment: This is now fixed in panads master, will be in 0.16.1.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'TimeWeek': ['6:40:00', '6:45:00', '6:50:00', '6:55:00', '7:40:00']})
>>> df["TimeWeek_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TimeWeek"], format="%H:%M:%S")
>>> print df
  TimeWeek       TimeWeek_date
0  6:40:00 1900-01-01 06:40:00
1  6:45:00 1900-01-01 06:45:00
2  6:50:00 1900-01-01 06:50:00
3  6:55:00 1900-01-01 06:55:00
4  7:40:00 1900-01-01 07:40:00
>>> df['TimeWeekDiff'] = (df['TimeWeek_date'] - df['TimeWeek_date'].shift().fillna(pd.to_datetime("00:00:00", format="%H:%M:%S")))
>>> print df
  TimeWeek       TimeWeek_date  TimeWeekDiff
0  6:40:00 1900-01-01 06:40:00      06:40:00
1  6:45:00 1900-01-01 06:45:00      00:05:00
2  6:50:00 1900-01-01 06:50:00      00:05:00
3  6:55:00 1900-01-01 06:55:00      00:05:00
4  7:40:00 1900-01-01 07:40:00      00:45:00
```