# Get time intervals between timestamps of rows and count value occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

Could you please help me out with the following issue?

The dataset that I have looks like this:

```
    id     timestamp             val1 
    ---------------------------------
    3301   2019-01-19 19:31:00   0    
    3301   2019-01-19 22:55:00   1            
    3301   2019-01-20 08:19:11   1             
    3301   2019-01-20 09:31:00   0                
    3301   2019-01-20 09:40:15   0
    3301   2019-01-20 09:55:13   0
    3301   2019-01-20 10:25:00   1
    3301   2019-01-20 10:31:00   0
    3301   2019-01-20 11:11:00   1
    3301   2019-01-20 11:13:00   1
    3301   2019-01-20 11:16:00   1
    3301   2019-01-20 11:17:00   0     
    4455   2019-01-19 19:31:00   0    
    4455   2019-01-19 22:55:00   1            
    4455   2019-01-20 08:19:11   1             
    4455   2019-01-20 09:31:00   0                
    4455   2019-01-20 09:40:15   0
    4455   2019-01-20 09:55:13   0
    4455   2019-01-20 10:25:00   1
    4455   2019-01-20 10:31:00   0
    4455   2019-01-20 11:11:00   1
    4455   2019-01-20 11:13:00   1
    4455   2019-01-20 11:16:00   1
    4455   2019-01-20 11:17:00   0
```

What I need to do is get time interval between rows with val1 = 0 and count the occurrences of different val1 values between those intervals (per id). The final dataset should look something like this:

```
    id     interval                 0_count   1_count 
    --------------------------------------------------
    3301   0 days 03:36:33.707000   0         0 
    3301   0 days 00:55:54.704000   0         5 
    3301   0 days 03:33:32.520000   0         1 
    3301   0 days 03:31:33.906000   0         0 
    3301   0 days 03:34:47.071000   0         3
    3301   0 days 04:32:35.465000   0         1 
    4455   0 days 03:36:33.707000   0         2 
    4455   0 days 00:55:54.704000   0         1 
    4455   0 days 03:33:32.520000   0         1 
    4455   0 days 03:31:33.906000   0         0 
    4455   0 days 03:34:47.071000   0         5
    4455   0 days 04:32:35.465000   0         0
```

Regarding the interval, I've found a helpful solution proposed by @jwilner [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29573471/1616582) using timedelta and shift():

```
    df["TimeWeek"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["TimeWeek"])
    (d['TimeWeek']-df['TimeWeek'].shift().fillna(pd.to_timedelta("00:00:00"))
```

but still struggling to select only specific rows based on value and apply counts to values in between.

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: can you explain how the desired output, means how you are getting these values

Comment: timedelta needs to be found only between val1 = 0 values. 0 and 1 in the output dataframe are a pivot of val1 counts.